# using check box to send multiple values

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

hi i have created a table one of the table columns is a check box and other data 
 now i know how i can post a single value with a check box bt how can i send an entire row
i.e. when the user checks the check box id,title,description.......req quantity gets posted to the servlet

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="4" 
       style="border-collapse: collapse" width="200%" id="AutoNumber1"
       align="center" bordercolorlight="#800000" bordercolordark="#800000 " class="left" >
     <tr>
         <td width="5%" align="center">
           <input type="checkbox" id=checked" value=<%= id%>/>
           <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
             Options</font>
       </td>
       <td width="15%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Title</font>
       </td>
       <td width="40%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Description</font>
       </td>

              <td width="15%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Company</font>
       </td>
      <td width="10%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Province</font>
       </td>
            <td width="10%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          District</font>
       </td>
            <td width="10%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Actual Quantity</font>
                 </td>
        <td width="10%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Required Quantity</font>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me

Comment: @Jigar: As far as I understand OP wants to submit whole row data of which checkBox is checked.

Comment: @ahsan if @Harry is correct then enclose everything in a form and process the row for which checkbox is checked .

Comment: @jigar harry is right, what do you mean by process the row the while row and i have already enclosed the table in a form. can u exactly tell me how i modify the above html

Comment: I meant have some names of component like company0,copmany1, iterate a loop through rows and see if for the row checkbox is checked then consider that row otherwise ignore

Comment: can u send a multidimensional array using checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your servlet check which `checkbox` are selected and depending upon that process all other data. e.g, if your HTML looks like this:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="4" 
       style="border-collapse: collapse" width="200%" id="AutoNumber1"
       align="center" bordercolorlight="#800000" bordercolordark="#800000 " class="left" >
     <tr>
         <td width="5%" align="center">
           <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" value=<%= id%>/>
           <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
             Options1</font>
       </td>
       <td width="15%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Title</font><input id="title_1" />
       </td>
       <td width="40%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Description</font><input id="description_1" />
       </td>

    </tr>
         <tr>
         <td width="5%" align="center">
           <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" value=<%= id%>/>
           <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
             Options2</font>
       </td>
       <td width="15%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Title</font><input id="title_2" />
       </td>
       <td width="40%" align="center">
         <font face="Arial" size="3" color="light blue">
          Description</font><input id="description_2" />
       </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

than in your servlet, check whether `checkbox_1` is selected? if yes than process `title_1` and `description_1`. And apply same logic for `checkbox_2`, `title_2` & `description_2`

Comment: the problem is that the entire table is being populated from the database and i am using json to print it on the html page so it is entirely dynamic i dont think the above shceme would be suitable

Comment: if i do this using an id 'checkbox[id]' for id and checkbox[id][name] for title would it work

Comment: @ahsan, thats great. I just gave a very basic idea. You have to tweak it as per your requirement.